# Making an M4V or MP4 repeat

Tags: photos, video, quicktime

Assuming I can [coerce Photos.app to export a video that works](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/439290/photos-app-unable-to-export-video-reliably), how do I make it repeat?  Photos only outputs one format, M4V, but I convert it with Handbrake to MP4 (for a huge size reduction).  It repeats in Photos, but neither file repeats and I don't know how to make them repeat.  I can also loop it within Quicktime, but that won't export a looping file either.

The reason for not playing it within QuickTime or Photos is that it is for a funeral and the funeral home has their A/V system wired up to Windows.

UPDATE: I ended up giving them the non-looping file, and the funeral director just went in and restarted it when it ended.  Something in their system played it without audio.  Bummer.

Comment: I'm fairly certain there's a "loop video" option in one of QuickTime's menus, is that what you're looking for?

Comment: That's not it.  Like I said, QuickTime will loop the video but it will not save a looping video.  The loop option only works if we play it within the app.

Comment: you never mentioned QuickTime in your post. Why do you want to have a single file with multiple copies of a video? Sounds like a waste of space/bandwidth.

Comment: You're right.  I meant to say both but I see I left it out.  I also didn't say I wanted "multiple copies in a single file," whatever that means.   Edited for clarity and detail.

Comment: there's no way to tell an mp4 to loop, the only way to do so is via the application that's playing it. Or open an editing program and create a larger video file with multiple loops, which will grow in size proportional to the number of loops you want.

Comment: @At0mic, that sounds like an answer.  I did have an app that claims to make it loop if I burn it to DVD.  Unfortunately, my laptop has a hardware or software problem that prevents burning discs on a drive that is known to work elsewhere.